# Getting information about outcome of the class React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making project, where you get books cards using Google Books API. I need to count amount of books I get in the end and print in in Header.js(after search). I think I need to add new parameter like 'count' in constructor that will get books.length but still don't know how to pass it in the end.

Books.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchArea from './SearchArea';
import request from 'superagent';
import BookList from './BookList';



class Books extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      books: [],
      searchField: '',
      sort: ''
    }
  }

  searchBook = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    request
        .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
        .query({ q: this.state.searchField })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          const cleanData = this.cleanData(data)
          this.setState({ books: cleanData })
        }) 
        
  }

  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState ({ searchField: e.target.value })
  }
  handleSort = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({sort: e.target.value})
  }

  cleanData = (data) => {
    const cleanedData = data.body.items.map((book) => {
      if(book.volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('publishedDate') === false){
        book.volumeInfo['publishedDate'] = '0000';
      }

      else if(book.volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('imageLinks') === false) {
        book.volumeInfo['imageLinks'] = {thumbnail: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pandorahearts/images/a/ad/Not_available.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141028171337'}
      }
      console.log(this.state.books.length)

        return book;
    })

    return cleanedData;
  }

  render(){
    const sortedBooks = this.state.books.sort((a,b) => {
      if(this.state.sort === 'Newest') {
        return parseInt(b.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0,4)) - parseInt(a.volumeInfo.publishedDate)
      }
      else if(this.state.sort === 'Oldest') {
        return parseInt(a.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0,4)) - parseInt(b.volumeInfo.publishedDate)
      }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchArea searchBook = {this.searchBook} handleSearch={this.handleSearch} handleSort={this.handleSort}/> 
        <BookList books={this.state.books} /> 
      </div>
    );
  }





}

export default Books;
```

SearchArea.js

```
import React from 'react'

const SearchArea = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="search-area">
      <form onSubmit={props.searchBook} action="">
        <input onChange={props.handleSearch} type="text"/>
        <button id="search" type="submit">Search</button>
        <select defaultValue="Sort" onChange={props.handleSort}>
          bled v<option disaalue="Sort">Sort</option>
          <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
          <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>

  )
}


export default SearchArea;
```

BookList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import BookCard from './BookCard';


const BookList = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="list">
      {
        props.books.map((book,i) => {
          return <BookCard
            key={i}
            image={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}
            title={book.volumeInfo.title}
            author={book.volumeInfo.authors}
            published={book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}
          />
        })
      }
    </div>


  )
} 

export default BookList;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  return(
    <header>
       <h1>Book Cards</h1>
       
    </header>
  )

}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Instead of load books in `Books.js` why don't you use a global state manager like Redux?

Comment: Well I got test for job and I was asked to do a bit more than I saw in vacation requests. I was only needed to know JS and basics of HTML, but appears I need to make a whole project using React and etc... So I am a bit embarassed, but this project is combination of everything I could find in the internet. At least its working, but it doesn't have everything I need (like counting books you get in the end). So its just happened that I found the way of loading books in Books.js the way it would work ( ._.)

Comment: Where (in code) do you want to put `Header` component? You should be able to add a `count` prop to your `Header` component, and pass `<Header count={books.length} />` (or if it's nested in `SearchArea`, pass `count` to `SearchArea` first)

Comment: Well wherever I try to make const count={books.length} I get an error: 'books is not defined'

Comment: Also the list I get is placed in Books.js